# Why is this map added using <Plug> not showing up?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, gvim

From my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap s <Plug>(easymotion-overwin-f)
```

This sets up an `nmap` which invokes the EasyMotion plugin when I type `,s`.

And that `nmap` works just fine, and is indeed triggered by `,s`.

However, if I do `:nmap ,s` or `:nmap <Leader>s` nvim prints "No mapping found."

Why?

### EDIT

Some output from `:filter /easy/ nmap`:

[image: filter]

Comment: You are mapping `nmap s` and querying maps via `:nmap ,s`. Those are not the same mappings. Maybe you can do `:filter /easy/ nmap` to find your mapping

Comment: @PeterRincker but `s` is not the mapping.  I believe that `easymotion-overwin-f` takes the argument `s` and creates the mapping `<Leader>s` which in my case is `,s`.  In any case, one way or another `,s` gets setup as the mapping... so I don't see why it wouldn't be listed.  I've edited the OP with the output from `:filter /easy/ nmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I do :nmap ,s or :nmap s nvim prints "No mapping found."
>
> Why?

`:map` (and variants) will return the mappings that Vim/NeoVim is currently using. In your setup you have:

```
nmap ,, <Plug>(easymotion-prefix)
```

There are a few more that [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) looks to map. Specifically ones that look like:

```
<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)N <Plug>(easymotion-N)
<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)n <Plug>(easymotion-n)
<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)j <Plug>(easymotion-j)
" So on and so forth
```

None of the mappings you have a `*` ahead of the Right-hand-side. See `:h map-listing`. This means the mappings will trigger other mappings (aka recursive mappings). This mean you can trigger `<Plug>(easymotion-N)` via `<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)N` which is also equivalent to `,,N`. There is no `,,N` mapping, but due to the maps being recursive and chording `<Plug>(easymotion-N)` can still be executed.

So when you execute, `,,s` the `,,` maps to `<Plug>(easymotion-prefix)` then waits for another possible letter to find another mapping. In this case a `s`. When the `s` is pressed it expands fully to `<Plug>(easymotion-s)`.

For more help see:

```
:h mapping
:h map-listing
:h :filter
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.  That all makes sense.  At the end of the day, I wanted to check if `,s` was free before I used it for something else.  It is not free.  However, as your post demonstrates, I cannot rely on `nmap ,s` to determine that (since it falsely reports that it is free).  Is there any method by which I can determine if a mapping is _actually_ free?

Comment: Easy motion is relying on recursive mappings to simplify customization. It really feels like they are trying to create a new mode. Typically most mappings will use `noremap` and this will not be an issue. Sadly, this type of mapping will always be annoying to chase down. The best I can say is you can use `<nowait>` to force a mapping if you want. See `:h :map-nowait`. This also highlights one of the reasons some Vimmers are wary of plugins.

Comment: Thanks again.  I certainly share those reservations about anything that makes debugging difficult.  That said, EasyMotion is _so damn useful_ that I'll put up with it in this case.